# .htaccess generates weird URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect the URL params to the new file. I have a page blog.php which generate the urls of the links like this: `http://localhost/project-DEV/blog/category/link-url-here/`

But when I click on the link it provides me this **URL:**

```
http://localhost/project-DEV/blog/blogs/blogs/blogs/blogs/blogs/blogs/blogs/blogs/blogs/blogs/blogs/blogs/blogs/blogs/blogs/blogs/blogs/blogs/blogs/blogs/uncategorized/hello-world/
```

Here is my .htaccess file in **blog folder**.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project-DEV/blog
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$  http\:\/\/localhost\/project-DEV\/blog\/index.php?$1 [L]
```

I have an `blog/index.php` file in blog folder. I want to send this `category/link-url-here/` to my `index.php` file.

Is it possible through `.htaccess` like I tried? And why this `.htaccess` code not working?

Comment: your creating a circular redirection, your rewrite path and rule both have `/project-DEV/blog` in them

Comment: @DevZer0 you're right it's circular, but having that string in both rules isn't why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try omitting the `http://localhost` part:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project-DEV/blog
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$  /project-DEV/blog/index.php?$1 [L]
```

If that doesn't help, you can add a condition to explicitly not rewrite `index.php`, to prevent a rewrite loop:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/project-DEV/blog/index.php$
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your `RewriteRule` will match pretty near every single request, *including those which have already been rewritten*, it is being called repeatedly. You need to rewrite the rule such that it doesn't match requests which already include your rewritten path, probably with a `RewriteCond`.

Also, consider reading [When Not To Use Rewrite](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/WhenNotToUseRewrite) and using the lighter, faster, and less-confusing `mod_redirect` instead of `mod_rewrite`.